# Unknown-8bit OpenPop

Tags: c#, openpop

I am using OpenPOP Pop3Client to monitor and import emails from a mailbox. I have received a few emails that are causing the following exception:

> "'unknown-8bit' is not a supported encoding name. For information on
>   defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the
>   Encoding.RegisterProvider method.\r\nParameter name: name"

Within the email there is some weird characters â€“ which when i googled said it was UTF-8 charset, one site suggested the following

`EncodingFinder.AddMapping("utf8", Encoding.UTF8);`

but this didn't work either, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding the following line of code before calling the GetMessage() method

```
EncodingFinder.AddMapping("unknown-8bit", Encoding.UTF8);
```